# Opening new form over another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have main form which has several buttons, each button opens new form. When i click button1, form1 opens and when i click button2, form2 opens but form1 goes back to the main form. I want functionality such that each new form opens over the parent form and the most recent form on the top.

This is my code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.Show();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 form = new Form3();
        form.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried Focus()? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each form has a topmost property, just set them to true

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.Show();
        form.TopMost = true;
        form.Activate();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.Show();
        form.TopMost = true;
        form.Activate();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 form = new Form3();
        form.Show();
        form.TopMost = true;
        form.Activate();
    }
```

Comment: it resolved 70% of my problem, now the problem is it is on the top of other applications too. I need the forms to be top on their parent only, not the top of other applications. Thnx

Comment: I removed them but the forms are still coming above my chrome browser :) . I think i would figure out that myself. thnx for help